# accessing mariadb COLUMN_JSON data in jscript

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, sequelize.js, mariadb

i am trying to access COLUMN_JSON data in javascript but am having issues.  i took a [mariadb JSON example](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/dynamic-columns/) and inserted it into a table like so:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myJsonColumn = COLUMN_CREATE('color', 'blue', 'size', 'XL')
WHERE 1
```

when i see it using mysqlworkbench, it looks fine:

Binary view:

```
0x00000000  7b 22 73 69 7a 65 22 3a 22 58 4c 22 2c 22 63 6f
0x00000010  6c 6f 72 22 3a 22 62 6c 75 65 22 7d
```

Text view:

```
 {"size":"XL","color":"blue"}
```

however, when the data is coming into javascript via sequelize, it looks like this:

console.log(data):

```
3sizecolor!XL!blue
```

console.log(util.inspect(data)):

```
<Buffer 04 02 00 09 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 33 00 73 69 7a 65 63 6f 6c 6f 72 21 58 4c 21 62 6c 75 65>
```

JSON.stringify(data):

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":  [4,2,0,9,0,0,0,3,0,4,0,51,0,115,105,122,101,99,111,108,111,114,33,88,76,33,98,108,117,101]}
```

i dont know the best way to interpret this data.  JSON.parse() or JSON.stringify() dont seem to work correctly for me.

the myJsonColumn is a BLOB datatype in the sequelize model:

```
  myJsonColumn    :  Sequelize.BLOB,
```

what might be the best way to interpret this data as a JSON structure in javascript?

Comment: Is "sequelize" needed?

Comment: i would prefer to use sequelize if possible.

Comment: But the JSON view is just JSON -- and Javascript understands JSON.

Comment: Agreed - but for some reason js is not recognizing it.  Maybe the sequelize people might have some ideas.
Or far more likely, i am doing something wrong once again.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-json  ??

Answer (score 0):

[sequelize.fn('COLUMN_JSON', sequelize.col('userJsonData')), 'userJsonData']

Comment: next challenge is to go back the other way with COLUMN_CREATE